# Asynchronous Web service in Java

Tags: web-services

How to create Asynchronous web service in java using eclipse??

I have created a normal web service in Java using eclipse. I am calling an external jar, which is taking long time to complete the process. By that time my web service is getting an exception throwing timed out exception.

In order to over come the problem, decided to create asynchronous web service, but couldn,t find proper details. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

no one responded to the question...
Found tentative solution for this....in order to over come the timed out exception, as soon as the request is received by the web service immediate response a unique id is sent acknowledging the request. A thread is initiated inside the web service for the corresponding request, which will take care of the process and stores the response in a table with a unique id for the request.